# With-As statement versus "=" Assignment?

Tags: python, python-2.7

What is the difference of using:

```
iFile = open("filename.txt",'r')
```

versus

```
with open("filename.txt",'r') as iFile:
```

Is one more efficient or allow more have more methods to access?  It appears to me that the with-as statement is temporary and unreferences after the following block ends.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your first example simply opens the file and assigns the file object to a variable. You will need to manage closing the file yourself (ideally, in a try-finally block so you don't leak the file)

The second snippet uses a context manager to automatically close the file as you exit the with block, including by returning or raising an exception

Comment: The file does not "leak" like in C, but it may take a while before it is garbage collected.